# Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] is always localhost

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing an ASP.NET 3.5 application with Visual Studio 2008.

My default page has some redirection code in the Page_Load method:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string sname = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"].ToLower();

        if (sname.ToLower().Contains("intranet"))
        {
        Response.Redirect("/intranet/Default.aspx");
        }
        else if ((sname.ToLower().Contains("extranet")))
        {
            Response.Redirect("/extranet/Default.aspx");
        }
        else {
            Response.Redirect("/web/Default.aspx");
        }
    }
```

I've modified my hosts file so that intranet and extranet redirect to my local machine.

```
127.0.0.1       intranet
127.0.0.1       extranet
```

I then type the URL http://extranet in my browser.

However, the problem is that the server variable value returned from Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] is always "localhost" and not "extranet"

Any help on how to get the right value?

Many thanks

Comment: Were you attempting to ensure that the server name here was extra lower-cased?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] gets the value I was looking for :)

Comment: Hooooly crap, I have been searching for this answer for an hour!  Cheers! I'd vote this up again, and buy you a beer if I could.

Answer (score 5):

Youre right
You want to retrieve the full address of the website that the request came to. Do not use "SERVER_NAME", use "HTTP_HOST". 
Read here,
http://www.requestservervariables.com/get-address-for-website

Answer (score 0):

`Server_Name` returns the server's host name, DNS alias, or IP address as it would appear in self-referencing URLs

Why don't you use `Request.URL`?

Comment: Same issue, the value from Request.URL is - Url = {http://localhost:4690/default.aspx}. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your host files only redirect the requests to a specific IP address - you cannot change the requesting machines name by editing them.